# array_splice() isn't working properly inside a loop

Tags: php, arrays, array-splice

This code works as expected and removes the array element when the value is either 5 or 10. But it only works when I have 1 value which is 5 or 10 in the array.

If I have more than 1 value which is 5 or 10 it removes only 1 of them and leaves the other elements in the array.

My code:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    if($somevar[$i] == 5 || $somevar[$i] == 10) {
        echo 'the sumvar'.$somevar[$i].' exists<br>';
        array_splice($somevar, $i, 1);
    }
}
```

As an example if I have: `[3, 5, 4]` the result is as expected: `[3, 4]`. But if I have an array like: `[3, 5, 10, 4]` it just removes the 5, but not the 10: `[3, 10, 4]`.

I can't seem to find it what I'm doing wrong and why my code doesn't work as expected?

Comment: If you use `array_splice()` like this it will remove the array element AND reindexed the array. So if you remove 5 with the key 0 you will then go to 1 with your loop, but the array gets reindexed to: `[0 => 10, 1 => 6]` and you skip 10, because you don't go back to 0. So just use `unset()` and reindex your array after it with `array_values()`. Also if you just want to filter out 10 and 5 use `array_filter()`

Comment: it seems a infinite loop?

Comment: For loop is incorrectly stated. Use `$i==10` a single `=` is assigning a value and not testing a value

Comment: sorry guys, i've updated my code. done the example code in a rush.

Comment: Can you please explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: if supposed 2 elements on the array were true for the if statement it should return the message. but then the same time removes it from the array with re-indexing. it works well if one element was true, but if its more than it, then it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You seem to miss that the array-elements are renumbered after the [splice-operation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php).

You would have to adjust the loop-variable:

```php
for($i = 0; $i &lt; sizeof($somevar); $i++) {
    if($somevar[$i] == 5 || $somevar[$i] == 10) {
        echo 'the sumvar'.$somevar[$i].' exists&lt;br>';
        array_splice($somevar, $i, 1);
        <b>$i--;</b>
    }
}
```